# rg.apache.rocketmq.remoting.exception.RemotingTooMuchRequestException: sendDefaultImpl call timeout

Tags: rocketmq

I just want to know why it throws this: sendDefaultImpl call timeout.
I know it maybe caused by firewall,but I have closed it.I cannot find the reasons.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.rocketmq.remoting.exception.RemotingTooMuchRequestException: sendDefaultImpl call timeout
at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.producer.DefaultMQProducerImpl.sendDefaultImpl(DefaultMQProducerImpl.java:667)
at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.producer.DefaultMQProducerImpl.send(DefaultMQProducerImpl.java:1343)
at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.producer.DefaultMQProducerImpl.send(DefaultMQProducerImpl.java:1289)
at org.apache.rocketmq.client.producer.DefaultMQProducer.send(DefaultMQProducer.java:325)
at com.zlx.mq.rocketmq.One.main(One.java:48)

Answer (score 0):

see [code logic here](https://github.com/apache/rocketmq/blob/b4240d5cea8d001c21b9c0d73f5aa700fcd0d568/client/src/main/java/org/apache/rocketmq/client/impl/producer/DefaultMQProducerImpl.java#L579). when doing retries, if time cost over timeout, no retry would go on.